# How to force automapper to ignore property, when mapping from a parent object

Tags: c#, automapper

I have a case which can be simplified down to this:

```
public class ASource
{
   public string ID { get; set; }
   public virtual BSource B { get; set }
}

public class BSource
{
   public string ID { get; set; }
}

public class ADestination
{
   public string ID { get; set; }
   public virtual BDestination B { get; set }
}

public class BDestination
{
   public string ID { get; set; }
   public bool Used { get; set; }
}

Mapper.Map<BSource, BDestination>()
   .ForMember(item => item.Used, property => property.MapFrom(item => item.ID.Contains("Used")));

Mapper.Map<ASource, ADesctination>();
```

How do I force automapper to ignore mapping BDestination.Used property only if the mapping occurs while mapping ASource => ADestination? When mapping BSource => BDestination I want the property to be mapped as stated in the mapping configuration.

Using AfterMpa() method to achieve this is not a solution - I am using queryable extensions, which do not work with AfterMap()

Comment: Ignore() skips the mapping. When you do ASource -> ADestination, you want the Used property to have its default value, false?

Comment: Yes, I want to do exactly that, however when I map BSource -> BDestination, I want the ForMember method to do that mapping.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
 Mapper.Map<BSource, BDestination>()
 .ForMember(item => item.Used,
 property => property.MapFrom(item => item.ID.Contains("Used")))
 .Ignore(source => source.theFieldYouWantToIgnore);
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is

```
Mapper.CreateMap<ASource,ADestination>()
    .ForMember(adest => adest.B, 
               m => m.MapFrom(asrc => new BSource { ID = asrc.B.ID }) );
```

So you map from a temporary `BSource` without its `Used` property set. Which, of course, is not too elegant, esp. not when `BSource` has many properties. Besides, I never like these "dirty" mappings, because most of the time they affect code where they are not visible. Configurations (in general) shouldn't control program flow.

I think I would keep it simple and create a second `BDestination` class for using in `ADestination`. But I don't know if this is a problem in your code as you may want to use the `BDestination` objects interchangeably (either from `A` or not).

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to do a couple of things:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<ASource, ADestination>()
    .AfterMap((src, dest) => { dest.B.Used = false; });
Mapper.CreateMap<BSource, BDestination>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Used, opt => src.ID.Contains("Used"));
```

So you default the value to "false", but after you map ASource -> ADestination, you fill in the "Used" value of the child property. This AfterMap only executes for the ASource/ADestination map.

This won't work with the queryable extensions, however. Building different expression trees based on mapping entry points is a bit too complex for now.

Comment: It seems, that you made a mistake there - the mapping configuration for the used property should be the other way around - when AfterMap'ping property should be set to false and when formemeber'ing it should perform a check.

Also I've noticed that you are using AfterMap() to achieve mapping I am after. is it possible to achieve this using something that works with queryable extensions?

Comment: So you only want "false" to be when it's doing the ASource -> ADestination map?

Comment: Yes, I do. However when mapping  BSource -> BDestination it should execute the logic described in the question

Comment: I fixed the answer above. Short answer - AfterMap doesn't work with queryable extensions. You might want to revise the question to include this constraint.